# How to create redirection from two domains in one VirtualHost directive in Apache?

Tags: apache-2.2, virtualhost, httpd.conf

I want users visiting either of `napiwki.kontestacja.com` and `napiwek.kontestacja.com` to be redirected to the same address. I'm using the following fragment in httpd.conf:

```
<VirtualHost *>
ServerName napiwki.kontestacja.com
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule .* https://tipanddonation.com/Kontestacja
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *>
ServerName napiwek.kontestacja.com
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule .* https://tipanddonation.com/Kontestacja
</VirtualHost>
```

I've tried different possibilities which should work according to my reading of the documentation but don't – it always causes just `napiwki` to redirect and `napiwek` to result in HTTP 403. Namely, I put these in a single `VirtualHost` directive:

```
ServerName napiwki.kontestacja.com
ServerAlias napiwek.kontestacja.com
```

or

```
ServerAlias napiwki.kontestacja.com napiwek.kontestacja.com
```

or

```
ServerAlias napiwek.kontestacja.com napiwki.kontestacja.com
```

I'm running `Server version: Apache/2.2.15 (Unix)`. Could you explain to me why the above configurations don't work as expected?

```
# httpd -S
VirtualHost configuration:
wildcard NameVirtualHosts and _default_ servers:
*:*                    is a NameVirtualHost
         default server stopacta2.org (/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf:1023)
         port * namevhost stopacta2.org (/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf:1023)
                 alias www.stopacta2.org
                 alias mail.stopacta2.org
                 alias webmail.stopacta2.org
                 alias admin.stopacta2.org
         port * namevhost kontestacja.com (/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf:1063)
                 alias www.kontestacja.com
                 alias mail.kontestacja.com
                 alias webmail.kontestacja.com
                 alias admin.kontestacja.com
         port * namevhost czat.kontestacja.com (/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf:1103)
         port * namevhost napiwki.kontestacja.com (/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf:1118)
         port * namevhost napiwek.kontestacja.com (/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf:1123)
         port * namevhost discord.kontestacja.com (/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf:1128)
         port * namevhost kontestgra.pl (/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf:1133)
         port * namevhost gra.kontestacja.com (/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf:1139)
         port * namevhost nowa.kontestacja.com (/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf:1145)
         port * namevhost www.kontestacja.com (/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf:1150)
                 wild alias *.kontestacja.net
         port * namevhost zus.kontestacja.com (/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf:1156)
Syntax OK
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<VirtualHost *>
  ServerName napiwki.kontestacja.com
  ServerAlias napiwek.kontestacja.com
  ...
</VirtualHost>
```

(or the other way around) is the right configuration.

I see that both napiwki.kontestacja.com and napiwek.kontestacja.com have the same set of several IP addresses. Are you sure that all of those are being answered by this configuration?

Comment: You mean the CloudFlare IP addresses?

Comment: As I wrote, it doesn't work then. Only napiwki.kontestacja.com redirects and requesting napiwek.kontestacja.com results in HTTP 403.

What IP addresses do you mean? Probably, as @MichaelHampton noticed, that's a Cloudflare thing.